# node.js HTTP request parsing (using net module)

Tags: http, node.js, response

Writing an HTTP simple server on top of Net node.js module, not using HTTP module.

I have a server listening at localhost:port with a socket opened.

```
socket.on('data', function(data){
    clientMsg += data;
});
```

Once I type the address in the browser I can see the GET request is in clientMsg.

In order to return a response I use:

```
 socket.on('close', function(){ something response generating here});
```

But this is not working well as it sends the response only once I click ESC or STOP in the browser.

So the question is, how can I know the browser finished sending the message and waits for a response, without closing the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the event connection instead of close.
[Event: 'connection'](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/net.html#event_connection_)

Also, this is the structure that is documented for such a server:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(c) { //'connection' listener
    console.log('server connected');
    c.on('end', function() {
        console.log('server disconnected');
    });
    c.write('hello\r\n');
    c.pipe(c);
});
server.listen(8124, function() { //'listening' listener
    console.log('server bound');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I saw that as well and couldn't understand, the c.pipe part, does it sends the input after the other side finished to stream the data ?

Moreover, when I connect to 127.0.0.1:8124 in Firefox, it does show the HTTP request, but it seems firefox still tries to retrieve data

Comment: c.write('hello\r\n'); Sends hello trough the socket. Pipe is a bit different http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/all.html#stream.pipe

Comment: Ok, I am testing the pipe method, I will accept once I fully understand that is the answer, thanks.